# How to execute/call javascript method within C# method in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, methods, execute

I'm developing a asp.net web application and I have this script in source code:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showWindow(URL, controlID, targetControlID,id)
    {
      noweOkno = window.open( URL + '?controlID='+controlID+'&targetControlID=' + 
         targetControlID+'&id='+ id, '_blank', 
         'menubar=no, toolbar=no, location=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, ' +
         'status=no, width=760, height=600, left=30, top=30')
      noweOkno.focus();
    }
   </script>
```

I can call it with this code:

```
Button4.Attributes["onClick"] = string.Format("showWindow( 'Child.aspx','{0}', '{1}','{2}');", tbVer.ClientID, Hidden1.ClientID, id_act);
```

my question is, how to call the javascript in some C# method like:

```
protected void someMethod()
{
-I want to call showWindow('Child.aspx','{0}', '{1}','{2}');", tbVer.ClientID, Hidden1.ClientID, id_act);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Microsoft provide ASP.Net AJAX for this model of mixing server side code and client code - see http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx for the ModalPopup control which seems to do what you want. You could also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx for a number of other options.

Comment: Just don't forget to user html, and url encoding where needed, otherwise special characters can mess up your script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register script block to run on page like :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"hwa","function_name;",true);
```

Comment: The above will add code at the bottom of the page. If you want it added just after the opening form tag, use RegisterClientScriptBlock(...)

Answer (score 0):

you can use clientscriptmanager

```
 ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AKey", "MyFunction();", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Comment: I've already read the article, but unfortunatelly didn't fully understand it, what are you refering when using Akey and MyFunction?Will read it again now:)

Comment: The `AKey` is just a key to identify your script, this is to ensure that your script is only registered once in the page

Comment: The text represented by `MyFunction();` can actually be any javascirpt code, the last parameter indicates whether the script should be enclosed in javascript tags when rendered or not

Comment: so for my example, MyFunction is showWindow('Child.aspx','{0}', '{1}','{2}');", tbVer.ClientID, Hidden1.ClientID, id_act);?